# How to know all times when a VM has been started in AZURE?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

Is there anyway to know all the times when a VM has been started in Azure?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

You can view this information by navigating to the Virtual Machine blade within the Azure Portal, then clicking on Activity log. In the Activity log pane, you can change the filter by setting Timespan to a date range you want, then type "Start" in the Search box and Apply the filter. This will list out times the VM was started.
[image]

Comment: If the system restarts itself and is not done by Azure, for example windows update auto reboot.  I don't believe the Activity log will capture this.